# WmpLib player.pause not working

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to play a file for some duration in C# the function is

```
void playfile(int duration)
{
  wmp.controls.play();
  Console.WriteLine("control is here");
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(duration);
  Console.WriteLine("control is here");
  wmp.controls.pause();
}
```

The player on calling starts the media player but does not pause.
The "Control is here" is printed twice but the player is not paused.
But when i present it in two different buttons it works fine.
eg.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  wmp.controls.play();            
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  wmp.controls.pause();
}
```

I want to develop a function to play a wav file for some time and  then stop and then play again for some time and then stop again.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.First drop a windowsmediaplayer control on a form then handle its openstatechanged event,in my code you will see the variable called duration which you will set its value like you need(from an up-down,textbox....),after that the code its self-explanatory:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        int duration = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition >= duration)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
                duration = 0;//reset it...
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            duration = 10;/* get the value from wherever you need to...*/
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"E:\music\Mike Terrana\Shadows of the Past\01 Pleasure Cube.mp3";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Interval = 500;
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OpenStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEventHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_OpenStateChange);
        }

        void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_OpenStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.openState == WMPLib.WMPOpenState.wmposMediaOpen)
            {
                t.Start();
            }
        }

    }
```